# C-Void pointer inside a generic list (Contains stucture)

Tags: c, list, pointers, generics, structure

I have 2 different stuctures but i need to contain them in the same generic list.

The structures are :

```
     typedef struct Val1{
       int num1;
       int num2;
       int num3;
     }Val1;



    typedef struct Val2{
     char name[50];
     char surname[50];
     int ID;
    }Val2;
```

And the list is:

```
typedef stuct list {
  void *value;
  struct node *next;
}list;

typedef struct L_head{
 node *head;
 int num_members;
 }L_head;
```

I need to use the same list implementation but the list needs to handle both of the 
strucrure types.I cant figure out how to initialize the list and put some elements in the list .Any advice will be helpfull.

Comment: So actually your list will be filled with void pointers, and each of these void pointers will point either to a `Val1` or to a `Val2`. Now imagine you go retrieve one of these void pointers from your list; how would you know if it points actually to a `Val1` or to a `Val2` ?

Answer (score 3):

The canonical solution for C would add a common initial field having distinct values to both structures.

```
typedef struct Val1 {
    int discriminator;
    int num1;
    int num2;
    int num3;
 } Val1;

typedef struct Val2 {
    int discriminator;
    char name[50];
    char surname[50];
    int ID;
} Val2;
```

If neccessary, you can define a new struct instead.
That has the advantage of preserving the previous layout and alignment guarantees:

```
struct packed {
    int discriminator;
    union {struct Val1;struct Val2};
};
```

Anyway, you could integrate it directly into the node:

```
typedef stuct node {
    struct node *next;
    int discriminator; /* You might want to reserve 0 for no content */
    union {struct Val1;struct Val2};
} node;
```

The technical term of the solution is "discriminated union".

Answer (score 0):

You can have a two element array of void pointers - One pointing to struct of type 1 and another to type 2. This should help to get the right structures with the right casting.

Comment: And how would you know which structure the void pointer points to when you retrieve a pointer from the list ?

Comment: As a rule if we have first element is marked for struct 1 and the second element to struct 2?

Comment: Sorry, disregard my first comment, it is rubbish. Actually the asker wanted to store them in the **same** list.

Comment: NP!. Having two element array of void pointers with rules as mentioned above should work for the same list,isn't?

Answer (score 0):

For adding the list items, you need to cast them to (void*).

In order to determine the type again upon access, you could add another field(enum) to the list, which stores it's type.

I bet this is some training or homework. If C++ is possible:
start using [std::list](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/) or [boost::list](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1%5f55%5f0/libs/fusion/doc/html/fusion/container/list.html) implementation.

Comment: And how would you check the size of the size of the structure the void pointer points to ?

Comment: @user3495204: the question is tagged C and not C++, so there is not boost of std.

Comment: Fixed my answer according to the comments.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to distinguish between the type of each of the nodes, you could resort to C unions, like in:

```
typedef struct Val1{
    int num1;
    int num2;
    int num3;
} Val1;

typedef struct Val2{
    char name[50];
    char surname[50];
    int ID;
} Val2;

union {
    Val1 val1;
    Val2 val2;
} Val;
```

Comment: If you have a pointer to `Val`, how would you know if it's actually a `Val1`or a `Val2` ?

Comment: And indeed I wrote "if you are able to distinguish...".  Of course, if the application doesn't know better then an additional flag would be mandatory.